# Azure performance between storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

My Web Role is on `StorageAccount1` and my Azure Storage Table on `StorageAccountB`.

My Web Role performs operations (inserts, updates, queries) on the Storage Table.

**Both of these Storage Accounts are in the SAME Affinity Group.**

Will performance be better if my Web Role and Storage Table are in the same Storage Account?

Comment: How can a web role be on a storage account? It's a role, it only consumes VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably confused by the "Publish" window in Visual Studio. The "Publish" window allows you to choose some info on how your application is deployed, like the Cloud Service but also the Storage Account. When you choose a storage account it doesn't mean your application will be stored in that storage account, it only means that the service package (the package which contains your application) will be uploaded there. Once the package is uploaded the Fabric Controller will take it and deploy it to your Cloud Service.

Besides that it's still a good idea to deploy your Cloud Service (Web Role) in the same affinity group as your Storage Account. By choosing the same affinity group Windows Azure will try to physically group your Cloud Services and Storage Accounts to minimize the network overhead.